# What's the idiomatic way of saying "hide your lips"?

Tags: idiom-request

[image: woman with her lips tightly pressed together]

What's the idiomatic way of saying "hide your lips"? I thought "bite your lips", but you're not biting your lips, your putting your lips inside your mouth. So what's the proper way to say it? I added a pic of someone doing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lambie's answer describes the action of curling one's lips inwards. But if the OP is looking for a shorter expression, then I would say that the young mother in the photo appears **tight-lipped**.

> 1 : having the lips closed tight (as in determination)
>   2 : reluctant to speak : TACITURN
>   *[Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/tight-lipped)*

Cambridge Dictionaries has

> Someone who is **[tight-lipped](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/tight-lipped)** is **pressing their lips together** to avoid showing anger, or is refusing to speak about something:

Answer (score 1):

**To suck in one's lips**.

The closed his mouth and sucked in his lips.

I can think of no other way to say this.

Alternative: to suck one's lips inward

EDIT: to turn one's lips inward is okay though clunky.

Comment: Hmm, it's weird. Are you sure we're talking about the same thing?

Comment: No, it is not weird. There is no other way to say it. To do this, you have to keep pressure on them to hide them. I know this is correct. Mind Your Mouth - Mouth, Lips, and Tongue Cues

"Be careful of pursing or licking your lips. Condit pursed his lips and sucked them inward more than 14 times in his famous 2002 television interview with Connie Chung." http://www.pattiwood.net/article.asp?PageID=2314

Comment: I guess pursed sounds better?

Comment: @blackbird Now, see, **pursing one's lips is the exact opposite**! Pursing your lips is pushing them outwards and together, as people do when doing a certain kind of kiss or "frowning" with their lips. It is a much more usual movement of the lips than sucking them in. Ok?

Comment: @Lambie _"There is no other way to say it."_ Just because you can't think of one doesn't mean there isn't another way. For example, I could say **"to put one's lips into one's mouth"** and that would still be an accurate description...